# Why are the last digits of the memory addresses same each time

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

This is more of a please help me understand than debugging question. So, I recently started working on C and while working with pointers for a while I came across this case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char *name="Bob";
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
                printf("Address is %0x and value is %ld",name,*name);
                printf("\n");
                name++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

I ran the program 3 times and got outputs like -->

```
Address is 9a756008 and value is 66
Address is 9a756009 and value is 111
Address is 9a75600a and value is 98

Address is ba49d008 and value is 66
Address is ba49d009 and value is 111
Address is ba49d00a and value is 98

Address is 2cb44008 and value is 66
Address is 2cb44009 and value is 111
Address is 2cb4400a and value is 98
```

My question is : The memory is allocated randomly each time so how come the last three digits in all three cases(got the same result each time I ran the program) the same? Is there any fixed rule for memory allocation?

Any information is appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: "The memory is allocated randomly each time" --> No. it is not random.  "Is there any fixed rule for memory allocation?" --> C does not specify a fixed rule.

Comment: It's just the way your operating system chooses to do it.  It's got a good reason or "rule", but you don't know what it is and should never count on it to be any particular way, as it can change at any reboot or even at any moment.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Yes, it is random. Good modern systems use [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The addresses are deliberately randomized by the program loader. This randomization only affects higher bits of the addresses.

If there are certain flaws in a program and an attacker knows some addresses where a program stores certain data or code, an attacker may be able to exploit the flaws to gain privileges or data they should not have access to. For example, if a program mistakenly accepts so much input it runs over the array the program reserved for the data, the extra input can overwrite other things in memory, such as a return address on the stack. When the attacker knows where code is located in memory, they can craft the input so that the return address is overwritten with an address selected by the attacker, allowing the attacker to choose what code the program executes.

To reduce the likelihood of this occurring, good modern program loaders use [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). When the program is loaded, the starting positions of various parts of the program in memory are selected randomly. This prevents an attacker from knowing exactly where the data or code will be.

The program loader may be limited in the starting positions it can select by various rules of the operating system and the executable file format. An operating system allocates memory only in units of some size called *pages*. 4096 bytes is a typical page size. The program may expect certain parts of its layout (constant data, program code, initialized non-constant data, and so on) to start at a page boundary. In this case, the program loader can only select random addresses that are page boundaries. If a page is 4096 bytes, each page starts at an address that is a multiple of 1000<sub>16</sub> (hexadecimal 1000 = 4096).

This means that starting addresses will have the form *xxx*000<sub>16</sub>, where *xxx* is a random value selected by the program loader and 000 is the start of a page. Anything within a page will have its offset affected by the changes in *xxx*, but there are no changes in 000 to affect it.

Thus, if some data is located at offset 678 relative to the start of its program section, its address will always have some value *xxx*678, and the *xxx* will vary between program runs, but the 678 will not.

These rules arise from the behavior of the operating system and the program loader, which are part of the C implementation. They are not part of the C standard.